# How to manually bundle two javascript files?

Tags: javascript, module, bundle

I'm writing code in Javascript for Espruino (an embedded platform) and there is a restriction: Only one file is allowed to be saved into the device.

For the following code to work:

```
var x = new require("Something");
x.hello()
```

`Something` module should be reachable from `main.js` file. The `Something` module is a separate file and looks like this:

```
function Something() {
    ....
}

Something.prototype.hello = function() {
    console.log("Hello there!");
}

exports = Something;
```

Question is; How can I concatenate these two files and still use the `Something` module as `require("Something");` format?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is found in Espruino forums:

```
# create bundle
BUNDLE="init.min.js"
echo "" > ${BUNDLE}

# Register modules via `Modules.addCached()` method
# see: http://forum.espruino.com/comments/12899741/
MODULE_NAME="FlashEEPROM"
MODULE_STR=$(uglifyjs -c -m -- ${MODULE_NAME}.js | sed 's/\"/\\\"/g' | sed "s/\n//g")
echo "Modules.addCached(\"${MODULE_NAME}\", \"${MODULE_STR}\");" >> ${BUNDLE}
uglifyjs -c -m --  init.js >> ${BUNDLE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use webpack to bundle the modules files into one file. 
I suppose that your current directory is your project directory

- First install nodejs  at:

> https://nodejs.org/en/download/
>   or sudo apt-get install nodejs

- Second, install webpack using this command

> npm i -g webpack

- bundle your module

To build your bundle run this command:

> webpack ./main.js bundle.js

- Note: your bundle.js will include all the module files that you have required in main.js

Comment: I can not use webpack, because this is not a web application. I also tried browserify with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is `https://www.npmjs.com/package/espruino` tool that has function to prepare code (concatenate + minimize) for uploading to your board.
I use it in my build proc that compiles typescript code to javascript and then prepares for board upload. Tutorial is here https://github.com/espruino/EspruinoDocs/blob/master/tutorials/Typescript%20and%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20IDE.md

Answer (score 0):

Yes like it's mentioned above, you need to uglify the code. You cannot use webpack or grunt here. They will transpile the code which will break your `require` libraries.

Here is how I achieved this in my case:

I put all my files inside a folder (like /src). Don't import one file from another. Then minify all files in the folder into a single file (eg. index.js)

> uglifyjs src/* --compress --mangle -o ./index.js

Then just upload this index.js into espruino. You need to install this library globally first.

> npm install -g espruino
>
> espruino -p /dev/cu.wchusbserial1420 -b 115200 --board ESP8266_4MB.json -e 'save()' index.js

I made a simple example here:

https://github.com/aliustaoglu/espruino-http-server